# Call ajax on the frontend

Tags: plugins, ajax

In my plugin folder I have two file 1. hello-ajax.php 2. myajax.js

and by shortcode I add this form on frontend

```
<form id="theForm" method="post">
 <input id="name" name="name" value = "name" type="text" />
 <input name="action" type="hidden" value="the_ajax_hook" />&nbsp; <!-- this puts the action the_ajax_hook into the serialized form -->
 <input id="submit_button" value = "Click This" type="button" onClick="submit_me();" />
 </form>
 <div id="response_area">
 This is where we\'ll get the response
 </div>
```

In plugin file I added js file as:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'my-ajax-handle', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'myajax.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
 wp_localize_script( 'my-ajax-handle', 'the_ajax_script', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );
 // THE AJAX ADD ACTIONS
 add_action( 'wp_ajax_the_ajax_hook', 'the_action_function' );
 add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_the_ajax_hook', 'the_action_function' ); // need this to serve non logged in users
 // THE FUNCTION
 function the_action_function(){
 /* this area is very simple but being serverside it affords the possibility of retreiving data from the server and passing it back to the javascript function */
 $name = $_POST['name'];
 echo"Hello World, " . $name;// this is passed back to the javascript function
 die();// wordpress may print out a spurious zero without this - can be particularly bad if using json
 }
 // ADD EG A FORM TO THE PAGE
```

So form is displaying at front end but in console Uncaught ReferenceError: submit_me is not defined

```
submit_me() is defined in myajax.js file as:

function submit_me(){
//alert(a);
jQuery.post(the_ajax_script.ajaxurl, jQuery("#theForm").serialize()
,
function(response_from_the_action_function){
jQuery("#response_area").html(response_from_the_action_function);
}
);
}
```

But this function is not working, and as far i know there is some problem in ajax call, so suggest me what did I wrong and how to make it work.

Comment: If that is literally the contents of your plugin file, you haven't hooked `wp_enqueue_script` and `wp_localize_script` in the correct action. look at the examples on [`wp_enqueue_script`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) codex page.

Comment: I am just learnintg to use ajax in wordpress...thanks for reply

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of your code looks ok to me. Is your script loaded? (Verify by viewing page source).  Per Milo's suggestion, this is how to properly enqueue your plugin's scripts:

```
// Enqueue your scripts
function load_my_scripts(){
     wp_enqueue_script( 'my-ajax-handle', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'myajax.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
     wp_localize_script( 'my-ajax-handle', 'the_ajax_script', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_my_scripts' );
```

I don't know if it is causing problems, but I would probably switch from using an `onclick` call and trigger the ajax via form submit.  Switching your JS file to the following:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    $('#theForm').submit(function(e){

        $.ajax({ 
            data: jQuery("#theForm").serialize(),
            type: 'post',
            url: the_ajax_script.ajaxurl,
            success: function(response_from_the_action_function) {
                $("#response_area").html(response_from_the_action_function);
            }
        });

    });

});
```

Answer (score -1):

Just need to add

```
e.preventDefault();
```

after the `$.ajax`

Also need to remove from the form:

```
onClick="submit_me();"
```